# react-native-google-signin and android.support.v4.net does not exist error

Tags: android, react-native

I have some problem when integrating `react-native-google-signin` into native android code. I use react-native 0.59.8 and i can't upgrade to 0.60 so far. Therefore I followed an instruction for older `react-native-google-signin` version which is 2.1.1. Unfortunately it's not working for me. It gives me some errors concerning androidX but as far as I know `react-native-google-signin` started using androidX from version 3.0.0 upwards, but i use 2.1.1 version which should not use androidX.

**Description**

The problem starts in sync proccess in Android Studio which gives me the following error:

[image: Manifest merger failed]

```
ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.
```

Now when I'm trying to build my project in Android Studio it gives me another error:

[image]

```
error: package android.support.v4.net does not exist
```

Interesingly, now problem concerns the package `@react-native-community/netinfo` which was working fine before I linked `react-native-google-signin` into my project. I would be very grateful if someone told me what's going on.

EDIT:

My dependencies section from `android/app/build.gradle` is as follows:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-google-signin')
    implementation project(':react-native-reanimated')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':react-native-community-netinfo')
    implementation project(':react-native-orientation')
    implementation project(':react-native-keychain')
    implementation project(':react-native-view-shot')
    implementation project(':react-native-video')
    implementation project(':react-native-fs')
    implementation project(':react-native-blur')
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation project(':react-native-navigation')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

Open your `/android/app/build.gradle` File, and check your `dependencies`.
Search for any instance of play-services of firebase, and see for two things:

1. the line starts with implements (instead of *compile*)
2. see if there are any `get latest Version` wildcard (that is the `+`-Sign) on it. (Example: `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+"`

*(If you don't found any component implemented with `+`-Sign, go on further down from topic "GO-ON-HERE" ⇓ in this answer.)*

Get those (in my example it is `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base` and search for it on [MVNRepository](https://mvnrepository.com/) to get an overview of available Versions.

Here you might choose the newest one, or one that definitely work with your used components and force your App to use it, by updating `/android/app/build.gradle` like this:

```
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0"){ force = true }
```

*(Note: I don't know, if it's play-services-base in your case, it's only an example)*

⇒ **GO-ON-HERE**

After that, switch to `/android` and run `./gradlew :app:dependencies`. This regenerate your dependency-tree for your Project.

Open the created Text-file and search for your updated Component:*com.google.android.gms:play-services-base* to see, where the component will be used.

You might find, that still some components use the `+`-Sign (`com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+`) in the dependency. To fix your issue, you need to patch them (maybe use [patch-package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package) to simplify this process) to also use the Version for your component (in our example "play-services-base") you've choosed above.

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Sadly it didn't help. I only have `com.facebook.react:react-native:+` with `+` Sign. The rest of dependencies have specific version i.e. `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'`. `./gradlew :app:dependencies` didn't output anything with `+` Sign as well.

Comment: What's about the dependency-tree. Are there  any `+` Sign dependencies?

Comment: I have downgraded `react-native-google-signin` to 2.0.0 and everything works fine. Out team consider upgrading `react-native` to 0.60.0 so we will move to version 3.0.0 anyway. Thanks for trying to help me out.